# how to add file names to a comma seperated string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm using the code below to list the files in a directory. How could I add the file names to a comma separated string?

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  DIR           *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir("/home/test/filename_test");
  char *start = "";
  char *filename_list = strdup(start);

  if (d)
  {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
      int size = sizeof(dir->d_name);

      printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);

      printf("size of name is %d\n",size); 
    }

    closedir(d);
  }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Allocate a buffer, use `sprintf()`...what's teh issue?

Comment: Do you really want to create it as a string? Or just want to display on the console with a comma separated?

Answer (score 0):

One easy-ish way to do this is

- allocate a zero-character, null-terminated char* using strdup("") before your loop
- increase it in size in each iteration. You can use realloc() to do this, which will preserve the existing contents, and make room to add more. You can work out how long the new buffer is by adding the old length, the length of the filename, the length of a comma, and the length of the final 0.
- Append your filename, etc., to the buffer using strcat().

You'll need some logic to avoid putting a comma at the end of the list, where it isn't followed by a filename.

The problem with this approach is that it can be inefficient in some systems, because of the repeated reallocation. A nicer approach is to use a buffer that you resize in chunks as you iterate. But if you're going to do that, it's probably easier just to use one of the many string-handling libraries that already exist for C.

Comment: Hi Kevin I am trying to implement your suggestion. In the code above, the size of the filename is being displayed as 256. Can you use the size of operator when dereferencing a pointer to a struct? Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but I'm not sure why you need the size of a struct. In the code example you gave, I couldn't see any need to do that. `sizeof()` applied to _any_ pointer will give you amount of memory the pointer takes up -- that's sometimes useful but, again, I don't see why you'd need that here. Better, I think, to post some code for people to look at.

Comment: Hi Kevin, my mistake, I was using `sizeof()` on `dir->d_name` but as you point out the returns the amount of memory that the pointer takes up. The reason why I thought to do this was because I needed to pass a size to `realloc()` but in hindsight I need to pass the number of chars in `dir->d_name` plus the sizes of the other items.